# Trying to delete all but most recent 2 files in sub directories

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu-12.04

I'm creating a cron that cleans subdirectories (first child only) of a specified folder of all but the most recent two files but running into issues.

These are my attempts:

```
find ./ -type d -exec rm -f $(ls -1t ./ | tail -n +4);
find . -maxdepth 2 -type f -printf '%T@ %p\0' | sort -r -z -n | awk 'BEGIN { RS="\0"; ORS="\0"; FS="" } NR > 5 { sub("^[0-9]*(.[0-9]*)? ", ""); print }' | xargs -0 rm -f
```

I also tried to create an array of files with the intention of going through the total minus 2, but the array was not populating with all files:

```
while read -rd ''; do      x+=("${REPLY#* }");  done < <(find . -maxdepth 2 -printf '%T@ %p\0' | sort -r -z -n )
```

Could someone please give me a hand and explain how they have done?

Comment: You have tried `ls -1t ./ | tail -n +4` What problem you are facing in this approach?

Comment: @abasu I have been warned off using ls to list the files.  Its apparently not safe?  Not sure why.

Comment: may be because the output is not reliable if your file name contains space. But I think, that's too much going into details to do day to day work. I mean `ls -trd */|head --lines=2|xargs rm -rf ` seems coming to me naturally when i think what i want to do step by step. rather than some fancy approaches.

Comment: @abasu a full explanation of why `ls` is unsafe is available at http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs. As for "good enough for day-to-day work", once you've had your first data loss incident caused by a bad filename (or, rather, by unsafe handling of filenames), you might rethink that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unlike the existing answer, this one NUL-delimits the output from find, and is thus safe for filenames with absolutely any legal character -- a set which includes newlines:

```
delete_all_but_last() {
  local count=$1
  local dir=${2:-.}
  [[ $dir = -* ]] && dir=./$dir
  while IFS='' read -r -d '' entry; do
    if ((--count < 0)); then
      filename=${entry#*$'\t'}
      rm -- "$filename"
    fi
  done < <(find "$dir" \
             -mindepth 1 \
             -maxdepth 1 \
             -type f \
             -printf '%T@\t%P\0' \
           | sort -rnz)
}

# example uses:
delete_all_but_last 5
delete_all_but_last 10 /tmp
```

Note that it requires GNU find and GNU sort. (The existing answer also requires GNU find).

Comment: Nice solution. what does the `[[ $dir = -* ]] && dir=./$dir` line do?

Comment: @ammonkc prepends `./` to any directory name starting with a dash, to prevent such names from being parsed as options by any command they're passed to. The `--` flag prevents that from happening from following positional arguments where it's available to be used, but its semantics are a bit more complicated than usual in the context of `find`.

Answer (score 13):

This lists all but the most recent two files:

```
find -type f -printf '%T@ %P\n' | sort -n | cut -d' ' -f2- | head -n -2
```

Explanation:

- `-type f` list only files
- `-printf '%C@ %P\n'`

  - `%T@` show file's last modification time in seconds since 1970.
  - `%P`  show the file name
- `| sort -n` do a numeric sort
- `| cut -d' ' -f2-` drop the seconds form output, leave only the filename
- `| head -n -2` show all but the last two lines

So to remove all these files just append pipe it through `xargs rm` or `xargs rm -f`:

```
find -type f -printf '%T@ %P\n' | sort -n | cut -d' ' -f2- | head -n -2 | xargs rm
```

Comment: This is brilliant thanks! I have changed the find command slightly, adding -not -name '*.php' just to specify not to delete php files but it works perfectly.

Comment: This doesn't safely handle filenames containing newlines.

Comment: Vote up, This is just an amazing and strait forward answer, Thanks for sharing your knowledge :)

Comment: How can this solution handle directories with only one or two files, which should not be deleted if there are no other older files.

Answer (score -1):

I just hit the same problem and that's how I solved it:

```
#!/bin/bash

# you need to give full path to directory in which you have subdirectories
dir=`find ~/zzz/ -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d`

for x in $dir; do
        cd $x
        ls -t |tail -n +3 | xargs rm --
done
```

Explanation:

- with tail -n +number you decide how many files you leave in subdirectories

Comment: This is unsafe for much the same reasons as many of the earlier answers. In addition, storing a list of files in a variable makes it impossible to handle some kinds of file names; so `dir` is not merely a superfluous temporary variable, but an additional, serious error.