# ubuntu bash script to make backup of /home/$user but keep the newest one

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, backup

I have a ubuntu bash script that makes a .zip file of the home directory of that user, for example admin, the name of the zip is like this YYYY_MM_DD_HH_MM_backup_admin.zip but for example after that I make another backup of the user admin2.

Those files are going to the folder /home/admin/files_zip, then with that I want to make a script that delete all the old backups of the same user and only save the newest one.

PD: sorry for my bad english :(

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Trying to delete all but most recent 2 files in sub directories](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19938730/1716578)

Answer (score 0):

Strongly recommended here use of [**`logrotate`**](http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl8_logrota.htm) utility available on most of *nix distros. It has following options of your interest:

```
compress
     Old versions of log files are compressed with gzip by default.

dateext
     Archive old versions of log files adding a daily extension like YYYYMMDD instead
     of simply adding a number.

notifempty
      Do not rotate the log if it is empty (this overrides the ifempty option).

rotate count
      Log files are rotated times before being removed or mailed to the address specified 
      in a mail directive. If count is 0, old versions are removed rather then rotated.
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I need to make a bash script :(

Comment: logrotate is used directly in BASH script only.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming

1. You check that your backup succeeded
2. You know the name of your newest backup file e.g. 2014_03_15_14_13_backup_admin.zip

You can find all zip files, ignore the specific one and remove from some directory:

find /some/directory -iname *zip ! -name 2014_03_15_14_13_backup_admin.zip -exec rm {} \;

#### lets create a script it accepts a username, finds the most recent zip file which contains this username, if found removes all other zipfiles containing the username

```
user=$1
if [ -z "$user" ]
then
echo "Please provide username" 
else
cd /home/$user/files_zip
# find last (newest) file  
last=`ls -rt *$user*.zip | tail -1`
# if there is a last file, remove all other zip files of user
[ ! -z "$last" ] && find /home/$user/files_zip -iname \*$user\*.zip ! -name $last -exec rm {} \;
fi
```

Comment: I dont know what .zip is the newest one for each user :(

Comment: Edited the answer to first find the latest .zip of some user. Hope it helps.